# Libreoffice oxt (script bash)

Tags: scripts, libreoffice

How can I do it using a bash script, insert the libreoffice oxt dictionary automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command called `unopkg` which does exactly that.

See `man unopkg` for details. Its description reads:

> LibreOffice is a fully featured office suite for the daily use with
>   all features you would normally expect in an office suite. There
>   exists many LibreOffice extensions all over the world. For example,
>   see http://extensions.libreoffice.org/ This tool allows managing the
>   extensions from the command line.

For examples see also: https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Extension_Manager